# Translation of a phrase "Catch the moment, ..." to Latin

Tags: idiom, sentence-translation, russian

I hope someone who speaks Russian could help me in translating a phrase "Лови момент. Цени мгновение." into Latin. I'm afraid the original meaning could be lost or transformed if I translate it to English, first. But I guess in English the phrase would sound like "Catch the moment. Appreciate the instant"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a well-known Latin equivalent in fairly common use : *carpe diem* (literally, 'seize the day), taken from Horace, Odes 1.11. The full phrase is *carpe diem quam minimum credula postero*, implying that you should take nothing on trust for tomorrow.

Although it's not a literal translation of the Russian, it catches the sentiment exactly.

Comment: It seems to me that the Russian quotation is actually a paraphrase of Horace.

Comment: carpo is etymologically “to pick, to cut off”. It is cognate with – among other things – the “harv-“ part of English “harvest”. I wonder whether “harvest the day” might not work very well in English.

Comment: @fdb 'Harvest the day', as you say, might work, but I've never seen it and wouldn't use it myself.

Comment: @fdb: In Dutch, the phrase is commonly rendered as "pluk de dag". Outside this phrase, using "pluk" with a day is probably as unusual as it is in English: its most typical use is with fruit. So perhaps "pluck the day" might work to a similar extent. I believe I have seen this translation used in English as well.

Comment: I believe we’ve already had a discussion on its equivalence https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/origin-of-seize-the-day-as-a-translation-of-horaces-carpe-diem