# Something that rolls off the tongue better than "carpe caeruleum caelum"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

After exchanging blue sky snapshots with my friend, he exclaimed:

> Seize the blue sky!

a reference to *carpe diem*, saying that we should embrace the beautiful weather and get the most out of it.

Of course instead of going outside, I've turned to Stack Exchange (uhoh!)

Google translate returns *carpe caeruleum caelum* the sound of which just doesn't pack the same punch as *carpe diem*.

Is there a way to capture the spirit of exclaiming that one should embrace and enjoy the blue sky and get the most out of it?

Or does *carpe diem* actually cover it?

Potentially helpful from [Origin of "seize the day" as a translation of Horace's carpe diem](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4938/6850)

> But "seize" is not a very close translation of *carpere*, which literally [means](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcarpo) "pick, pluck, gather, harvest".

---

[image: Seize the blue sky!]

Comment: The verb "cherish" may mean this? The latin verb "foveo" can be translated thus.

Comment: Do you want to specifically speak about the blue sky or just good weather? In English they can well be phrased indistinguishably, but in Latin you might need to decide. Too literal a translation can end up meaning something like "take control of the heaven".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks, I think that "don't waste such a beautiful-looking day by staying indoors" where it's the exhilarating feeling of being outdoors under such a clear, crisp blue sky that one should not waste. One should stop everything else and take full advantage of the opportunity that's been presented.

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças see above, yes I think that that could work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *caeruleum caelum* you could simply say *caeli caerula* or simply *caerula*. What's that? It's the neutral plural of the collateral form *[caerulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcaeruleus1)*, and it literally means “the deep blue of the sky” or simply “the deep blue,” where the sky is implied. But *caveat scriptor:* simple *caerula* could also be the deep blue of the sea (and analogously, the sea itself). So you can drop *caeli*, but you should only do it if the context is unambiguous. A pithy thing you could say would be:

> Carpe caerula.

I might add that *caeruleum caelum* is not the usual way to express the idea of “fair weather”; for that, *caelum [serenum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dserenus1)* is very frequently employed. Here too the *caelum* is often dropped, and you can say:

> Carpe serenum.